# I need to add a replica forest to another host in a MarkLogic cluster

Tags: marklogic

The MarkLogic documentation provides an example for creating a forest and a forest replica using the /manage/v2/forests Rest API as follows:

---

```
$ curl --anyauth --user admin:admin -X POST \
-d '{"forest-name": "Documents", "host": "host-1.marklogic.com", "database": "Master", \
"forest-replicas": {"forest-replica":[{"replica-name": "Documents-R", "host": "host-3.marklogic.com"}]}}' \
-i -H "Content-type: application/json" http://localhost:8002/manage/v2/forests
```

This creates a "Documents" forest on "host-1" with a "Documents-R" replica forest
on "host-3."  Note that both hosts must be in the same cluster.

However, I would like to add a replica forest for an existing forest, but need help with the syntax, perhaps using `/manage/v2/forests/{id|name}/properties (PUT)`.

Aside from the above question I also have the following issue:

My admin console doesn't allow me to specify forest replicas - it's just blank and I don't know how to enable it when creating a forest replica in the admin console.

Comment: Do you have the replica forests created already? The Admin UI will only populate available/unassigned forests in the dropdown for replicas to assign in the *forest replicas* section at the bottom of the configure tab for a forest.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have already created that primary forest, you will need to create the replica forest, then attach it to the primary as an HA-replica (two steps).

1. Create the HA replica in a similar manner as you did for your primary forest.
2. Then you can set the "`forest-replica`" property with the ID of the HA-replica forest using [https://docs.marklogic.com/REST/PUT/manage/v2/forests/[id-or-name]/properties](https://docs.marklogic.com/REST/PUT/manage/v2/forests/%5Bid-or-name%5D/properties)

> Note: The properties described here are for XML payloads. In general they are the same for JSON, with the exception that, in JSON, `failover-hosts` and `forest-replicas` are expressed in singular form. For example, in JSON, `failover-hosts` is instead `failover-host` and the format is: `"failover-host":["hostname"]`.

Once the HA-replica forest has been created, it should also appear in the dropdown for available forests to assign as a replica on the forest status page in the Admin UI, so that would also be an option.

Comment: Thanks folks, I have been able to create the scripts for creating and then attaching the failover forests to the primary. It was a little bit of trial by error to get the appropriate syntax for the attachment scripts especially using the JSON schema. To work that, I created one manually and then performed a get request for the forest configuration in JSON, which revealed the correct proper payload and updated my attachment scripts accordingly.

Comment: FYI - I'm still a novice to stackoverflow. I can't seem to close out these tickets or give credit for useful answers, all of which I would like to do.

Comment: In order to accept an answer, click the grey checkmark next to it https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: And if you can add (and accept your own) answers to your own questions, if you have a more complete answer with info that would help others!